# Linker input file unused c++ g++ make file

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, static-libraries, gnu

I am unable to figure out what is causing this error that I keep getting upon making my project:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: -lncurses: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

And my make file looks like this:

```
CC = g++

LIB_FLAGS = -l ncurses

FLAGS = $(LIB_FLAGS)

DEPENDENCIES = window.o element.o

# FINAL OUTPUTS
main: main.cpp $(DEPENDENCIES)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o main.out main.cpp $(DEPENDENCIES)

# MODULES
window.o: main.h classes/window.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c classes/window.cpp

element.o: main.h classes/element.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c classes/element.cpp

# CLEAN
clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm main.out
```

Everything compiles okay, but I'm just curious what is causing this error message and what it means..

Comment: Don't passe linker arguments if you're just compiling (`-o`) and not linking. (BTW, those linker args (`-lfoo`) should usually go at the end of the command line.)

Comment: By linker arguments, do you mean I shouldn't include the $(FLAGS) for the element.o and window.o?

Comment: @Mat I think you mean `-c` not `-o`?

Comment: By the way, this is not an error, just a warning.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not give link flags when you compile (-c flag) your source files. Take a look for this example makefile (very similar as in makefile docs)

```
CPP = g++
CPPFLAGS =-Wall -g
OBJECTS = main.o net.o
PREFIX = /usr/local

.SUFFIXES: .cpp .o

.cpp.o:
        $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<

.o:
        $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@

main: $(OBJECTS)
main.o: main.cpp
net.o: net.cpp net.h


.PHONY:
install: main
        mkdir -p $(PREFIX)/bin
        rm -f $(PREFIX)/bin/main
        cp main $(PREFIX)/bin/main


clean:
        rm -f *.o main
```

Answer (score 5):

You are passing linker options to a compiler invocation together with `-c`, which means that linking is not performed and thereby `-l` options are unused. In your case, your `LIB_FLAGS` should not be in `FLAGS`, but instead specified in the the `main: ...` rule:

```
main: main.cpp
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(LIB_FLAGS) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned already you're passing linker-related flags at the compile stage. Usually you want different flags for compiling and linking, e.g.

```
CC = g++

CPPFLAGS = -Wall -g -c -o $@

LDFLAGS = -l ncurses -o $@

DEPENDENCIES = main.o window.o element.o

# FINAL OUTPUTS
main: $(DEPENDENCIES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(DEPENDENCIES)

# MODULES
main.o: main.h main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) main.cpp

window.o: main.h classes/window.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) classes/window.cpp

element.o: main.h classes/element.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) classes/element.cpp

# CLEAN
clean:
    -rm main $(DEPENDENCIES)
```

Comment: By (GNU) convention, you should really change `LFLAGS` to `LDFLAGS`.