# Unable to compile C program on Mac, but able to compile on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, compiler-errors, clang

I facing some trouble compiling my programming assignment on my local machine. The program is distribute to us with makefiles and compilation commands that are known to work on the school's Scientific Linux servers. My local machine is Mac OS X El Capitan.

When I compile my program running make on my Mac, I get the following error that prevents compilation from proceeding:

```
myid-MacBook-Pro:mp6 myid$ make
gcc -g -lm -std=c99 -Wall -Werror  -c lodepng.c
clang: error: -lm: 'linker' input unused
make: *** [lodepng.o] Error 1
```

But when I push that very same code as work in progress to the Linux servers and compile there, everything works fine. The linux servers use gcc and not clang:

```
[netid@linux-a2 mp6]$ make
gcc -g -lm -std=c99 -Wall -Werror  -c functions.c 
gcc -g -lm -std=c99 -Wall -Werror  main.o lodepng.o imageData.o functions.o -o mp6 -lm
gcc -g -lm -std=c99 -Wall -Werror  -c test.c 
gcc -g -lm -std=c99 -Wall -Werror  test.o lodepng.o imageData.o functions.o solution.o -o test -lm
```

In the makefile, these are the variable definitions:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -lm -std=c99 -Wall -Werror
```

and the target definition for loadpng.o

```
lodepng.o: lodepng.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c lodepng.c
```

I would appreciate any help on understanding this error and overcoming it.

Thank you very much.

Also, on this note, I thought I would say that I've noticed a subtle difference between Clang and GCC. It seems to me that even warnings generated by Clang would prevent the compilation to proceed so the warnings behaves like errors. But for GCC, if it generates warnings, it still compiles the object file. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're getting a compilation error on your Mac because you're trying to pass linker commands (i.e. -lm) into a compilation(i.e. -c). [Do not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525579/linker-input-file-unused-c-g-make-file) give link flags when you compile (-c flag) your source files.

In the other compilation snippet you provided, the unused linker command seems to pass by unnoticed which isn't a good thing.

For your last question, the flag -Werror should force all compilation warnings to become errors -- which is exactly what you are describing.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for you clarification! Then its really funny, does that mean vanilla GCC seems to not enforce the elimination of unused linker commands? No wonder Clang is becoming the preferred compiler!